# Hide parameter in url

Tags: java, rest

When searching with email, the email will be showed in url.
What‘s the better way to hide the email part? Use POST?
Thank you.

URI：
https://myproject/api/tenants/A1/users?email=my@example.com&page=1&pageSize=10

Service：

```
@GET
@Path("/tenants/{tenantsId}/users")
@Produces("application/json;charset-UTF-8")
public Response index(
@PathParam("tenantId") String tenantId, 
@DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("page") int page,
@DefaultValue("10") @QueryParam("pageSize") int pageSize,
@QueryParam("email") string email) 
throw .....Exception;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could "encrypt" it with public/private keys so then on the server side you could decipher it and being part of URL wouldn't mean much as just leaving some ciphertext in the URL. Or use POST. Or use JWT https://jwt.io/